# Do we have that $y\in R\setminus R^\times$, such that $y^n\mid x$ for every $n\in \mathbb N\implies x=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is it true that if $R$ is an integral domain with $1$, and for $x\in R$ there exists $y\in R\setminus R^\times$ such that $y^n$ divides $x$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $x=0$?

I think this is not true in general, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: What about if our ring is a field?

Comment: Probably you want to make the assumption that $x$ is not invertible (and, possibly, a non zero divisor).

Comment: It may be that whatever restrictions we put on, we can construct a counterexample. For example we certainly don't want $y$ to be $1$, or a unit.

Comment: If one notes the statement in terms of ideals, then the question asks about the nature of $\bigcap_n (y)^n$. For noetherian rings, this is precisely answered by Krull's Intersection Theorem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes, I added that condition. Thanks.

Comment: To make this an interesting question, you also need to add at least the hypotheses that $R$ is an integral domain (or else some non invertible $x$ with $x^2=x$ provides a counter example $y=x$), and that $R$ is Noetherian (or else one has other easily found counterexamples). Unless you are asking to see such simple counterexamples explicitly.